# How to run test kitchen in docker and use a local driver

Tags: docker, test-kitchen

I have a development environment set up inside a docker container with chef and all the dependencies installed (including kitchen gems, bundler, etc). If I wanted to run kitchen from my host and converge / test within a docker container, I could easily do that using the kitchen-docker driver. However, if I am running kitchen within a docker container, should I be using something like kitchen-local (https://github.com/ianschenck/kitchen-local) to converge locally? If I use the driver set to docker and run within docker, it does converge, but seems to do a `[Dummy]` run.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend an updated [fork of kitchen-local](https://github.com/gengo/kitchen-local).

```
gem 'kitchen-local', git: 'https://github.com/gengo/kitchen-local.git'
```

After installing the Gem, add the following to your `.kitchen.yml`, as shown in [this example](https://github.com/gengo/kitchen-local/blob/master/.kitchen.yml).

```
driver:
  name: local
transport:
  name: local
```

If you installed Chef in your Dockerfile, add the following to prevent Chef from installing it.

```
provisioner:
  sudo: false
  require_chef_omnibus: false
  chef_omnibus_root: /opt/chefdk
```